# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS - Steam "Fatal Error: Failed to load steamui.so"

Tags: 16.04

Please help. I just got this new pc with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on it but it can't run steam. Everytime I launch it says

```
Fatal Error: Failed to load steamui.so.
```

I'm really new here so a quick and straightforward solution is greatly appreciated. It would be great if you could just provide codes for the terminal so I can simply paste them there to solve this issue.

Here's my specs

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Recently after updating to 22.04 LTS, I was getting the same message, but looking in a terminal window when launching Steam I was seeing this message:

```
Failed to load steamui.so - dlerror(): /home/terrance/.steam/debian-installation/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libva-x11.so.2: undefined symbol: va_fool_postp
```

To fix it I only needed to install the `libva-x11-2` library

```
sudo apt install libva-x11-2:i386
```

Now Steam launches without a problem.

Comment: I had the same error when going from LTS to 22.10. I suppose that if you get an updated package for the audio that this package is removed, so you have to reload. Same solutions works fine, and yes you *need* the i386 package even on a 64 bit install.

Answer (score 1):

For me this was solved by:

1. Creating `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/steam.conf` with the contents:

   ```
   /usr/lib32
   /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa
   ```
2. Running `sudo ldconfig` to update the shared library cache
3. installing/reinstalling the 32bit mesa libraries:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
   ```

[Source](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2233005)

Answer (score -1):

Change the settings here:

**Additional Driver** → **Change another driver for your graphics card**.

Answer (score -1):

Same thing happened twice on my pc even thought i am running ubuntu 14.04 lts. Try installing it from the terminal.

sudo apt-get install steam